# Xcode 7: changing product bundle identifier

Tags: xcode, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, xcode7, bundle-identifier

I'm setting up Jenkins to automate the build process. In particular, for my needs, I'd like to be able to set different bundle identifiers.

I'm using the Xcode Jenkins plugin to set the bundle identifier:

[image: Jenkins Xcode plugin - Code signing & OS X keychain options]

The problem is that this will change the bundle identifier in the Info.plist file and in MyTarget > General > Bundle Identifier. But it won't change the bundle identifier in Build Settings > Packaging > Product Bundle Identifier.

The same thing happens if I do it manually.
I create a new project in Xcode 7. By default, the three values are:

[image: Info plist before][image: target general before][image: packaging]

When I change the value in the `Info.plist` file like this:

[image: Info plist changed]

The other two value will be:

[image: target general after]
[image: packaging after]

So how you can see the value in Build Settings is not changing. If I'm in Xcode I change that value manually, but if I'm building the project in Jenkins this is a bis issue.

Anyone encountered the same problem? How do you tackle it?

Thanks!

Comment: Encountering the same issue since today. I use `plistbuddy` shell command to change the bundle identifier. It changes the `info.plist` but doesn't change the bundle identifier inside the build settings in xCode.

Comment: Big thanx, didn't realize it has to be changed in 3 places!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Faced the same problem.

The `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` is a variable in your `project.pbxproj` file. Change that to whatever you want and it will reflect both in your `Info.plist` as well as the project settings.

Comment: so I should pass `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$CB_APP_ID` to xcodebuild, right?

Comment: that worked. For the record, I'm passing `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$CB_APP_ID` to `xcodebuild` command.

Comment: how you and where you added this `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=$CB_APP_ID`?

Comment: I have added in `Custom xcodebuild arguments` like :
`PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = 'com.w.test'` but it is not changing in build settings :(

Comment: @LucaTorella can you please help

Comment: yes it's just an extra `xcodebuild` argument. `xcodebuild PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER="com.w.test"`

Answer (score 30):

[udit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32868273/2450847) is correct. The best practice is in plist set Bundle ID value as $PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER. Then in Build Settings, use different configurations(Debug, Release .etc) to set up different bundle ID by required:
[image]

You don't need xCode plugin to change bundle id anymore but need to specify configuration in there.

[image]

Comment: in most of the cases that's the best practice, I agree. But I want all these parameters to be customizable. Basically I want to have a web interface were the customer can add p12 file, mobile provisioning profile, bundle identifier, and they'll get a customized .ipa

Comment: @Aoke Li- This seems like a better approach. I just have one doubt with this. When I use different bundle identifiers depending on  build configurations, which value will reflect in Xcode summary general pane?

Comment: @Rashmi Ranjan mallick- So after you setup your config file and build locally, you will notice the bundle ID in general pane also got update. And since there is nothing be injected in jekins build time for this area, the slave will work exactly like your dev machine.

Comment: @AokeLi- Actually, I am not using Jenkins. I am building manually using Archive function. My scenario is- I want to use different bundle IDs for different configuration (as you demonstrated).

Comment: This fails if you’re building 3rd party dependencies in your project, beacause all modules must agree on the build configurations. Most only support default ones Debug and Release. :/

Answer (score 15):

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910416/modify-product-bundle-identifier-in-project-pbxproj-of-xcode) for a simple solution to replace $PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER using shell command like -

`sed -i '' 's/com.example.oldbundleid/com.example.newbundleid/g' project.pbxproj`

You can pass your variables accordingly using Jenkins/Shell.

Alternative approach to do this is using [mod-pbxproj](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj).

`python -m mod_pbxproj -b -af PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=com.example.newbundleid -rf PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=com.example.oldbundleid project.pbxproj All`

//edit

Old bundle id can be fetched by -

`awk -F '=' '/PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER/ {print $2; exit}' project.pbxproj`

This can be stored in a string variable and used in place of `com.example.oldbundleid`

Comment: It would be nicer with a solution that you didn't need to know the old bundle identifier.

Comment: Updated my solution. It fetches the stored bundle ID value from `.pbxproj` to replaced. @turingtested

Answer (score 3):

For **xcode 8.x**

Changing app name under Targets > your_app_name - Info > addition of a new property key *does not make complete changes of app name everywhere* throughout the project.

When you do this, your project runs smoothly in your mac alone (i.e., in the system which you used to do these changes, as all your property keys & identities will be saved in your system). When you try to use your project in another system, yo'll get this weird error that your project is missing if in case your using pods in your project.

So, to overcome this, all you gotta **do some changes in Build settings**, leaving General tab and Info tab untouched.

Under **Targets > Build settings**, scroll to **Packaging**.

Change your **Product name** to the desired name & **Product bundle identifier** to the new one. Once you do this, automatically your project display name & bundle id changes to the new one in General tab.

Comment: I'm using XCode 9 and this doesn't work.  App explodes when firing it up in Simulator.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `bundle id suffixes`, don't set the `Product Bundle Identifier` on `General` tab of the `Target Settings`.

Set it on the `Build Settings` tab.

For example:

```
com.company.app${BUNDLE_ID_SUFFIX}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also see the data in plain text by going to Targets and select "Levels" which will show a column including the Bundle Identifier.

[image]