# Modify PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in project.pbxproj of Xcode

Tags: bash, unix, sed, xcode7, plist

I'm trying to modify the `project.pbxproj` file of Xcode project using `sed` shell command on Mac Terminal to replace a string. I want to replace the field -

`PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.example.71b9b4f2`

to

`PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.example.14a32d1e`

Command used -

`sed -i 's/com.example.71b94f2/com.example.14a32d1e/g' project.pbxproj`

which produces the following output error-

> sed: 1: "project.pbxproj": extra characters at the end of p command

I was earlier using `Plistbuddy` shell command to modify the field `CFBUNDLEIDENTIFIER` in `info.plist` but that doesn't change `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` in Xcode 7 build settings anymore.

My main aim is to modify the PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER field of BUILD SETTINGS in Xcode using command line or any script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OSX requires the extension to be explicitly specified. The workaround is to set an empty string:

```
sed -i '' 's/com.example.71b94f2/com.example.14a32d1e/g' project.pbxproj
```

Comment: Yup. Tried that, didn't work in this case. Already found this [here](http://myshittycode.com/2014/07/24/os-x-sed-extra-characters-at-the-end-of-l-command-error/)

Comment: it's weird because i just tried and it works for me on my macbook pro

Comment: do you mind using python script? i can write python script for you

Comment: found an alternative solution as well using [mod-pbxproj](https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj). Will share a detailed answer on how to use this as well for others.