# iOS xcodeproj: Update PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER using shell script

Tags: ios, shell, jenkins, sed

I am working on a shell script that will perform some tasks prior to a Jenkins build.
Using shell script how can we change the PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER for an iOS application? Do we need to use sed command in the shell script or there is any other way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: If you know the old bundle identifier have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910416/modify-product-bundle-identifier-in-project-pbxproj-of-xcode

Comment: I haven't given sed command a try yet but would like to know if it is a good practice to use it in shell script? Also I will not be having older PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER when I use sed command. Isn't there any other alternative available?

Comment: Are you building the project from the command line (xcodebuild) or writing a script to change things before opening it in xcode?

Comment: The intended shell script is for making some changes in the xcode project's various files like changing some assets etc. The script will be run by a Jenkins job