# Xcode 8 PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I get following error when trying to build/test a app on my phone

```
Showing Recent Issues Bundle identifier is missing. QRCodeReader doesn't have a bundle identifier for the Debug build configuration. Add a value for PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER in the build settings editor.
```

How can I change this to let the app work. 
I got the app from a tutorial on appcoda [here](http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/), I'm trying to build a super easy barcode scanner. My xcode/swift at beginnerslevel.
I used the build file to convert it to swift 3 and when simulating it, it worked. But when simulating it on my phone it didn't.

Can I add my own bundle_identifier and where do I sign this up?

I'm working on osx Sierra , Xcode 8

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Target -> Build Settings -> Product Bundle Identifier -> Expand it -> Debug -> put here same bundle id from Release.

Comment: The original maker from the tutorial's com.gabrieltheodoropoulos.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}is in there, what do I change it to?

Comment: you should put here whatever you want. The typical bundle id looks like com.<your company name>.<your app name> i.e: com.Facebook.facebookApp. The only important think is, that it should be the same as defined in itunesconnect, in case you want upload it to appstore. But if you say, that there is already some value, the problem is in something different.

Comment: I think this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862253/xcode-7-changing-product-bundle-identifier

Comment: From what I've read so far, It has to do with not having a developer individual account?